# Can Accelerator be killed by a nuclear weapon?

Tags: a-certain-magical-index, a-certain-scientific-railgun, a-certain-scientific-accelerator

There is an episode where Accelerator mentions to Last Order if I recall correctly (it could be another character) that he/she shouldnt worry about someone who can't be killed even by a nuclear bomb. But in the other hand, his brain has been overwhelmed with information sometimes, when he had to kill the virus for example, and I think there were other moments where he received many vectors and couldnt fight back 100%. I assume a nuclear bomb has many vectors to process. Since he appears in several series/media (3 different animated series, mangas and light novels) plus there could be data in official databooks if they exist, I thought this question might have been probably answered.

Can Accelerator be killed by a nuclear weapon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume that he would have no trouble deflecting the initial blast because it's just a straightforward shockwave (no dark matter shenanigans here). But there's more to worry about than just the initial shockwave.

During Accelerator's fight with Touma after he sets off the dust explosion, he actually does contemplate on such a scenario. He notices that the temporary lack of oxygen from the dust explosion almost killed him, and comments that he probably wouldn't be able to survive a direct nuclear blast for the same reason. In the novels, he considers the idea of oxygen tanks to remedy that problem, since some are made the size of hairspray bottles.